# Android, Realm: Is enough to set only delta for update Realm object?

Tags: android, realm

Realm 3.5.0

My Android application must create/update Realm object from json.

Here POJO:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    @Required
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String contacts;   
}
```

Here snippet that create/update Realm object from json:

```
 public void addOrUpdatePerson(final String personASJson) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Person.class, personASJson);

            }
        });
    }
```

My steps:

1. I want to create new **Person**.
2. As result I has the next json:

   *{"id": 1,  "address": "Address 1", "name": "Person 1", "contacts": "My contacts"}*
3. Call method "**addOrUpdatePerson**" and new **Person** success create on Realm. 
   OK!
4. Now I want to change content of field "contacts" in the same **Person**.
5. So I create new json:

   *{"id": 1,  "address": "Address 1", "name": "Person 1", "contacts": "My NEW contacts"}*
6. Call method "**addOrUpdatePerson**" and **Person** success updated with new value of field "**contacts**". OK!

But when I need to update exist **Person** I don't want to pass WHOLE json.

But I want to pass ONLY delta.
So for update exist **Person** I can use the next json:

```
{"id": 1,  "contacts": "My SUPER NEW contacts"}
```

As you can see I pass only Person **id** and only delta (field "**contacts**").

I again call method "**addOrUpdatePerson**" with this json and **Person** success updated with new value of field "**contacts**". OK!

I will confirm that to update object in Realm I can set only delta with **Person.id**. Not need to set WHOLE json.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. Our JSON methods can work with a partially defined JSON structure. Any fields not set, will just be ignored.

Comment: This is correct also for method "realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myPojo)" ?  Is it right?

Comment: Method "createOrUpdateObjectFromJson" work only if has mapping 1:1. In another situations method "createOrUpdateObjectFromJson" fire exception: "Could not map json for Realm DB"

Comment: The names has to match, yes, but not all fields needs to be present

Comment: I has custom json deserializer for my POJO. Is Realm has method like "createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(pojo, deserializer)" ? This will be solve the problem.